# Stubbing a method with dependend generic arguments using mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Im trying to stub a method with dependend generic arguments like so:

```
<T extends Foo> void exampleMethod(Type<T> arg1, T arg2);
```

using Mockito.
But when I try to do this like this

```
verify(mock).exampleMethod(isA(Type.class), any());
```

it does not work but gives me an unbounded generics error. (I know this is not stubbing but the example is easier this way and it boils down to the same thing I think.)

If anybody could help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is that `any()` returns a type Object, which isn't valid for type `T`. The generics are only responsible for a warning. Use `any(Foo.class)` instead:

```
public class MockTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MockTest sandbox = Mockito.mock(MockTest.class);

    // gives a type safety warning suppressable with @SuppressWarnings
    verify(sandbox).exampleMethod(isA(Class.class), any(Foo.class));

    // gives an unchecked cast warning suppressable with @SuppressWarnings
    verify(sandbox).exampleMethod((Class<Foo>) isA(Class.class), any(Foo.class));

    // gives no warnings because the cast in the helper method below
    verify(sandbox).exampleMethod(isAClassOf(Foo.class), any(Foo.class));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static <T> Class<T> isAClassOf(Class<T> clazz) {
    return isA(Class.class);
  }

  <T extends Foo> void exampleMethod(Class<T> arg1, T arg2) { }
}
```

Comment: This yields a "The parameterized method ... is not applicable for the arguments (Type, Object)" error. Hence it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry; tested out my code now that I'm back at computer. Fixing up with `any(Foo.class)` as needed. By the way, you may want to adjust the syntax in your question a bit; `T extends Foo arg2` isn't valid.